# Trying to write a function that creates global symbols in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I have a global list of words (symbols) and I want to write a function that can add new words to it. I can add new words but then I run into errors that they are unbound. how can I write a function:

```
(defun add-symbol (aNewWord) (... ))
```

and have it create a global symbol 
using the argument I type as its name?

Perhaps I would like a user to add new symbols during runtime.

Comment: [push](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm)?

Comment: Do you mean symbol in the sense that you can use it as a variable name? If so, there's no way to globally do that; you do that at the package level.

Comment: What are you going to push symbols or bindings? can you give an example of how you are going to use it and the expected effect? You are probably looking for a [hash](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_has.htm) instead

Answer (score 3):

Use `PUSH` to add an element to a list.

```
(defvar *word-list* ())

(defun add-symbol (new-word)
  (push new-word *word-list*))

(add-symbol 'hello)
(add-symbol 'friday)
*word-list*
```

Output is:

```
(FRIDAY HELLO)
```

If you were getting errors about unbound variables, you probably forgot to quote the symbols when you used them as arguments to the function. If you don't quote a symbol, it's treated as a variable name and tries to use its value.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to control the namespace for user created data and not have it leak into your program structure.  It is thus preferable to create some (maybe top level) datastructure inside of which you hold the data.  Do *not* create variables from user data.

Keys for such data might be symbols, which you can create with `intern`.  If you want to create new symbols with names given by the user, you might want to use either the keyword package:

```
(defun make-user-symbol (string)
  (intern string '#:keyword))
```

or some pristine package for exactly those symbols:

```
(defpackage #:user-symbols)

(defun make-user-symbol (string)
  (intern string '#:user-symbols))
```

One flexible data structure for such things are hash tables:

```
(defvar *user-data* (make-hash-table :test #'eq))

(defun add-user-data (keystring value)
  (setf (gethash (make-user-symbol keystring) *user-data*)
        value))
```

You could also just use strings, of course, but then the hash table needs to use `:test #'equal`.

If you want to have a set of words as symbols (though I do not see the need for such a conversion), your data structure might be a list:

```
(defvar *words* ())

(defun add-word (string)
  (push (make-user-symbol string) *words*))
```